# Google Spreadsheets - highlight if same cell is exist

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet, conditional-formatting

I have spreadsheet with two tabs (House1, House2).

Example: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZaYgBEfqe9S9Qc526HjkhquJMDQKitvv8khjQIyZfMA/edit#gid=0

In House2 tab I have some names database.

[image]

In House1 tab I write new names.

[image]

Question:
How set highlight if new name in House1 tab will same like some name in tab House2?

Answer (score 1):

Set up conditional formatting on the range A:A in Sheet1. Use as a custom formula

```
=countif(indirect("House2!A:A"), $A2)>0
```

and see if that works?

Check out the spreadsheet you shared and check out the conditional formatting applied to column A in sheet 1.

Comment: Working perfect!